# A few problems with my javascript sample. Please help

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

Alright, so I'm trying to get a page to load some js at the end of it's loading. I think I got it, but now it's saying I'm not getting a number with this line:

```
parseInt(document.getElementById('canvas').style.width);
```

It should be "480px" but it's NaN.

It also said the line `document.getElementById('ss')` was null.

Here's the full thing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Cypri Designs</title>    
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon1.ico" type="image/x-icon" />    
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--    
            //Variables to handle game parameters
            var gameloopId; 
            var screenWidth;
            var screenHeight;
            var gameRunning = false;
            var ctx;

            var playerX = 0;
            var playerY = 0;

            //Create images
            var playerImg = new Image();


            //Wait for DOM to load and init game
            window.onload = function(){
                init();
            };

            function init(){
                initSettings();
                initImages();

                //add event handler to surrounding DIV to monitor mouse move and update mushroom's x position
                /*$("#container").mousemove(function(e){
                    mushroomX = e.pageX;
                });*/

                //add event handler for clicking on start/stop button and toggle the game play
                document.getElementById('ss').onclick = function (){

                    toggleGameplay();
                };
            } 

            function initSettings()
            {
                //Get a handle to the 2d context of the canvas
                ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

                //Calulate screen height and width
                screenWidth = parseInt(document.getElementById('canvas').style.width);
                screenHeight = parseInt(document.getElementById('canvas').style.height);

                playerX = 100;
                playerY = 100;
            }

            function initImages(){
                playerImg.src = "images/player.png";
            }
            //Main game loop, it all happens here!
            function gameLoop(){ 

                //Clear the screen (i.e. a draw a clear rectangle the size of the screen)
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

                ctx.save(); 
                ctx.drawImage(playerImg, 0, 0);

                ctx.restore();
            }

            //Start/stop the game loop (and more importantly that annoying boinging!)
            function toggleGameplay()
            {
                gameRunning = !gameRunning;

                if(gameRunning)
                {
                    clearInterval(gameloopId);
                    gameloopId = setInterval(gameLoop, 10);
                }
                else
                {
                    clearInterval(gameloopId);
                }
            }
        //-->
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="ss" type="button" value="start/stop" />
        <div id="container" style="border:1px solid; cursor:none; width:480px; height:320px;">
            <canvas id="canvas" width="480px" height="320px" >
            Canvas not displaying.
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the width you should use the element property instead of the style property:

```
document.getElementById('canvas').offsetWidth
```

Answer (score 2):

The "width" and "height" properties you defined with the canvas are not style properties; they are attributes of the canvas object.  They define the width and height of the canvas's coordinate system, not the display height and width.

The canvas will fill its parent container, which is 480px and 320px.  As mVChr mentioned, you could get this through "offsetWidth" (with cross-browser caveats), or by using a library like jQuery that will compute it for you in a cross-browser way:

```
$("#canvas").width();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few problems. First, these lines where you are getting the width are the cause of your NaN result.

```
            screenWidth = parseInt(document.getElementById('canvas').style.width);
            screenHeight = parseInt(document.getElementById('canvas').style.height);
```

The width and height properties return a string value, 480px and 320px respectively. Since those are string values, the parseInt call will return NaN because 480px is not a number. I'd recommend switching to offsetWidth as mVCr and user85461 recommended.

And I don't see any problem with the document.getElementById('ss') line. When I ran it, the click event was setup and fired correctly.